# How to use result of cypher query output in GDS algorithm

Tags: neo4j

I have one Bipartite Graph made of users and document storing which client has read which record.
I ran the following query which creates a graph and shows common docs read by users. Now I want to use results in the GDS algorithm to create clusters.

I am not getting how to project results from the below query to GDS algorithm. I know I need to use graph projection.
In projection we pass nodes and relationships but how to pass the result of this query?

```sql
MATCH (n1:ClientInfo)-[:ACCESSED]->()<-[:ACCESSED]-(n2:ClientInfo) 
WITH n1, n2, count(*) AS commonDocs
WITH n1, n2, commonDocs, count{(n1)-[:ACCESSED]->()} AS n1Docs,
  count{(n2)-[:ACCESSED]->()} AS n2Docs
WHERE commonDocs >=2
RETURN n1, n2, 
  apoc.create.vRelationship(n1, 'HAS_COMMON_DOCS', {commonDocs:commonDocs}, n2)
```

Below query not working for me

```sql
MATCH (n1:ClientInfo)-[:ACCESSED]->()<-[:ACCESSED]-(n2:ClientInfo)
WITH n1, n2, count(*) AS commonDocs
WITH n1, n2, commonDocs, count{(n1)-[:ACCESSED]->()} AS n1Docs,
  count{(n2)-[:ACCESSED]->()} AS n2Docs
WHERE commonDocs >= 5 AND n1.peopleCode <> 310962818
WITH n1, n2,
  apoc.create.vRelationship(n1,'HAS_COMMON_DOCS', {commonDocs:commonDocs}, n2)
CALL gds.graph.project(
       'users',
       ['ClientInfo', 'DocInfo'],
       ['ACCESSED','HAS_COMMON_DOCS']
     )
YIELD graphName AS graph, nodeProjection, nodeCount AS nodes, 
  relationshipProjection, relationshipCount AS rels;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't project virtual relationships to a GDS graph (your second query has other syntax errors but as the approach isn’t going to work, it's not worth fixing them).

Instead you can use a `UNION` query (shown here in the `CALL` braces) to project both the `ACCESSED` relationships that already exist in your graph as well as the 'virtual' `HAS_COMMON_DOCS` relations:

```sql
CALL {
    MATCH (source:ClientInfo)-[:ACCESSED]->()<-[:ACCESSED]-(target:ClientInfo)
    WHERE source < target
    RETURN source, target, 'HAS_COMMON_DOCS' AS relType, {commonDocs: count(*)} AS props
    UNION
    MATCH (source:ClientInfo)-[:ACCESSED]->(target)
    RETURN source, target, 'ACCESSED' AS relType, {} AS props
}
WITH gds.graph.project(
    'common_docs',
    source,
    target,
    { 
        sourceNodeLabels: labels(source),
        targetNodeLabels: labels(target),
        relationshipProperties: props {.*},
        relationshipType: relType 
    }
) AS g
RETURN g
```

You can add `WHERE` clauses in the `UNION` query to filter on e.g. user ids etc. I left out `n1Docs` and `n2Docs` as they aren't used in your example.

Comment: Hello @finbar , Is it not possible to pass two relationshipType: 'HAS_COMMON_DOCS' and ACCESSED.

Comment: I tried one query but giving me error . updating it main question

Comment: To your first question: yes it's possible. See my updated answer. To your second question, there are a few syntax errors, but instead of fixing them, try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use cypher projection (https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/graph-creation/graph-project-cypher-projection/#cypher-aggregation-relationship-properties).
The linked example projects a graph with a relationship property.

Replace your last return clause with the projection.

Answer (score 0):

GDS does not allow you to project virtual nodes or relationships. You can, however, use [Cypher projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/graph-creation/graph-project-cypher-projection/) to put relationships in the projection that do not actually exist in the database (along with the associated nodes), which may be equivalent to what you are trying to do.

This version of @FinbarGood's answer may do roughly what you are trying to do in your second query:

```
MATCH (n1:ClientInfo)-[:ACCESSED]->()<-[:ACCESSED]-(n2:ClientInfo)
WHERE n1 < n2 AND NOT 310962818 IN [n1.peopleCode, n2.peopleCode]
WITH n1, n2, COUNT(*) as commonDocs
WHERE commonDocs >= 5
WITH gds.graph.project(
    'users',
    n1, n2, 
    { relationshipProperties: {commonDocs: commonDocs},
      relationshipType: 'HAS_COMMON_DOCS' }
) AS g
RETURN g.graphName AS graph, g.nodeCount AS nodes, g.relationshipCount AS rels;
```

Notes:

- `n1 < n2` lets us avoid using the same pair of `ClientInfo` nodes twice.
- The projection will only contain the generated `HAS_COMMON_DOCS` relationships and their associated nodes.